# how can I create a blinking red dot using tkinter in an transperent window/surface. PS: I want to make an warning alert

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have created a transparent window with a red dot inside it using Pygame and win32api. Please help me to replicate using Tkinter which I think will be better.

```
import pygame
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import time

RED =  (255,   0,   0)
fuchsia = (255, 0, 128)  # Transparency color
size =(width, height) = (40, 40)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.NOFRAME) # borderless, use pygame.NOFRAME
# Create layered window
hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE,
                       win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED)
# Set window transparency color
win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(*fuchsia), 0, win32con.LWA_COLORKEY)

while True:
    screen.fill(fuchsia)  # Transparent background
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (20, 20), 20)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.25)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, fuchsia, (20, 20), 20)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example using tkinter:

```py
import tkinter as tk

TRANS_COLOR = "white"

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True) # borderless window
root.geometry("-10+10") # top-right corner
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", TRANS_COLOR) # set transparent color
root.attributes("-topmost", 1) # make it on top of other windows

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=40, height=40, bg=TRANS_COLOR, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

dot = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 40, 40, outline='')

def blinking_dot(i=0):
    colors = (TRANS_COLOR, "red")
    canvas.itemconfigure(dot, fill=colors[i])
    root.after(250, blinking_dot, 1-i)

blinking_dot() # start blinking dot
root.mainloop()
```

Note that it works on Windows.